# HSPICE -mp -mt options for Ubuntu

Tags: linux, hspice

I was reading part of the hspice tutorial, I found that, there is a multiprocessing option:

"hspice -mp [process_count] -mt [thread_count] -i input.sp -o output_file"
"Note: Running both MP and MT simultaneously is limited only to LINUX."

Is there anyway to use those options on Ubuntu system?
I tried it, I got "Syntax error: Bad fd number".

Comment: What was the exact command you have run? This is a generic linux error when tying redirect the IO stream in a shell https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1460684

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes, when I was searching it, I noticed many people faced it when they were doing other simulations. I ran this option on linux and Ubunto system. The Ubuntu system gave me this error and linux was fine. Therefore, I thought maybe Ubuntu is the reason. I used: "hspice -mp -i xxx.sp"

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. I had to change the /bin/sh link from dash to /bin/bash:

```
sudo rm /bin/sh
sudo ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh
```

Thanks to [this](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=221179) bug report for the idea